# failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag to java.util.List.\n\n1

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle, converters, modelmapper

Model mapper version : 2.3.4

Gradle project.

ERROR:  ["ModelMapper mapping errors:\n\n1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter@10ce0586 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag to java.util.List.\n\n1 error"]

what could be the solution?

Comment: You need to read [ask], pay attention to the details; then come back and edit your question to follow those guidelines. The amount of effort you put into  writing a question determines the amount of effort people will be willing to spend reading it and writing answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.